# Click Activation Email Link, Redirect to "Success" Page VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, email, registration

I've created a registration web form that redirects users to a page saying "Check your email to complete registration". The next step for them is to check their email and click the link provided in the email. Up to this point, everything works. However, when the link is clicked, it redirects them to the registration page again. I cannot figure out how to change this to go to the page designated for them that says "Your account is successfully been activated."

```
Using mm As New MailMessage("****@outlook.com", txtEmailAddress.Text)
        mm.Subject = "Account Activation"
        Dim body As String = "Hello " + txtFirstName.Text.Trim() + ","
        body += "<br /><br />Please click the following link to activate your account"
        body += "<br /><a href = '" + Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace("VB.aspx", Convert.ToString("VB_Activation.aspx?ActivationCode=") & ActivationCode) + "'>Click here to activate your account.</a>"
        body += "<br /><br />Thanks"
        mm.Body = body
        mm.IsBodyHtml = True
        Dim smtp As New SmtpClient()
        smtp.Host = "smtp.live.com"
        smtp.EnableSsl = True
        Dim NetworkCred As New NetworkCredential("****@outlook.com", "****") 
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = True
        smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred
        smtp.Port = 587
        Try
            smtp.Send(mm)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Email was not sent")
        End Try
    End Using
```

Comment: You mean that link that is getting added to body of email is not "VB_Activation.aspx?ActivationCode=..." ?

Comment: Can we see the VB_Activation.aspx code behind?

Comment: No, changing the links "VB.aspx" and "VB_Activation.aspx?ActivationCode=")" doesn't change where the page gets redirected. That's why I'm wondering if there's something else I need to add to this block of code.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't even have pages called "VB.aspx" nor "VB_Activation.aspx". This block of code I got from open source code on how to send an activation email.

Comment: If VB_Activation.aspx doesn't exist then how will your user ever get redirected to it?

Comment: Well, I did create a page for them to be redirected to, but I suppose I need to try changing that existing page to "VB_Activation.aspx" as you say.

Comment: The file name in your code should match the filename of the page you created.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this line:

```
body += "<br /><a href = '" + Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace("VB.aspx", Convert.ToString("VB_Activation.aspx?ActivationCode=") & ActivationCode) + "'>Click here to activate your account.</a>"
```

must be appended somehow with your website activation page.

Comment: No.  This will not help him.

Answer (score 0):

Create the page VB_Activation.aspx within your web application and write code to activate the user using the ActivationCode that's being sent to it.  If that file already exists make sure the filename in your code matches what you have created to handle activating the user.

Also, you could change this line:

```
    body += "<br /><a href = '" + Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace("VB.aspx", Convert.ToString("VB_Activation.aspx?ActivationCode=") & ActivationCode) + "'>Click here to activate your account.</a>"
```

To

```
    body += "<br /><a href = 'http://www.yoursite.com/VB_Activation.aspx?ActivationCode=" & ActivationCode & "'>Click here to activate your account.</a>"
```

Comment: Ok, I tried this. It still sends me to the registration page from before the email is sent. I am completely baffled.

Comment: What is the name of the file you created to handle activation?

Comment: I made the change to that line as stated above and am getting this error: 
"
Parser Error 
  Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

 Parser Error Message: 'MaridersWeb.VB_Activation' is not allowed here because it does not extend class 'System.Web.UI.Page'.

Source Error: 

Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="VB_Activation.aspx.vb" Inherits="MaridersWeb.VB_Activation" %>"

Comment: The file for handling activation is:

"<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="VB_Activation.aspx.vb" Inherits="MaridersWeb.VB_Activation" %>"

changed from "ActivateAccount" to "VB_Activation"

Comment: I'm sorry you may need to do some ASP.Net study to help you with the basics, try this book:  http://www.amazon.com/Beginning-ASP-NET-Using-VB-NET-Ullman/dp/1861005040